# Tool to automate FTP uploads on a Mac

Tags: macos, ftp, automation

What tool would you recommend to automate several FTP uploads on a Mac? It should have a queue (so not all transfers are at the same time) and the ability to retry x times if the transfer fails. It should also be able to overwrite existing files without asking user confirmation, and report any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what all options there may be for gui tools, but if you are at all comfortable with Terminal.app and the command line... I would suggest [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) might fit your needs.  Actually, normally I'd suggest [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) but it appears that OS X doesn't ship with it by default, though there are plenty of pages on the 'Net describing how to d/l and install it on a Mac if you really want it instead; the two ([wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) & [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)) are supposed to be functionally equivalent to some degree.  Depending on what you want/intend to do... wget may be the better choice.

Comment: Commandline is perfect, actually it's much better. What are he advantages of wget over curl?

Comment: wget is designed more for recursively downloading ftp or http sites (can be used for mirroring); curl is more of a one-shot affair but it can handle things like forms, cookies, etc. which make it more useful for grabbing info from a web page.  They overlap a bit in some areas but are really intended for two different (but related) purposes.  This [document](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html) on the cURL site does a good job of going over the differences between the two.  My personal experience with cURL is somewhat limited, sorry.

Comment: Whoops... my mistake.  Looks like wget is download-only.  Since you want to do FTP upload, your options may be a lot more limited... like cURL or [wput](http://wput.sourceforge.net/) (upload version of wget).  Again, cURL comes default on OS X.  This [comparison table](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/comparison-table.html) may be useful...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a GUI, Cyberduck can most likely take care of this job.